# Domino Agent and GSON - access denied

Tags: java, gson, lotus-domino

In an Java agent I want to use GSON to parse json. But when I try:

```
String jsonReceived = "{'product':'IBM Domino','args':{'since':'1970','current':'9.0.2'}}";
Product product = (Product) gson.fromJson(jsonReceived, Product.class);
```

I get the message:

java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")

I recently changed the java policy to the max:

```
grant { 
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
}
```

So what is restricting me?

Here is the complete code:

```
import lotus.domino.*;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() throws JsonParseException{

        String msg = null;

        lotus.domino.Session session = getSession();
        OpenLogItem oli = new OpenLogItem(session);

        try {

            AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

            msg = "Agent " + agentContext.getCurrentAgent().getName() + " using runtime version:" + System.getProperty("java.runtime.version");
            oli.logEvent(msg, OpenLogItem.SEVERITY_LOW, null);

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

            msg = "after new Gson()";
            oli.logEvent(msg, OpenLogItem.SEVERITY_LOW, null);

            String jsonReceived = "{'product':'IBM Domino'}";
            Product product = (Product) gson.fromJson(jsonReceived, Product.class);

            msg = "after gson.fromJson";
            oli.logEvent(msg, OpenLogItem.SEVERITY_LOW, null);


      } catch(Exception e) {
          oli.logError(e);
      }
   }

    public class Product{
        String product;
        String msg = null;

        lotus.domino.Session session = getSession();
        OpenLogItem oli = new OpenLogItem(session);

        public Product(){
            msg = "Product() // constructor";
            oli.logEvent(msg, OpenLogItem.SEVERITY_LOW, null);
        }

        public String getProduct() {
            return product;
        }

        public void setProduct(String product) {
            this.product = product;
        }

        /*@Override
        public String toString() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "product: " + getProduct();
        }*/


    }
}
```

Comment: Would a LotusScript agent be an option? There are very simple JSON parser libraries available...

Comment: i have become rusty writing in LotusScript...

Comment: So what? Take some schuurpapier, be pragmatic and give it a try ;-)  I use the JSON library originally created by Alan Faubel, with some improvements, to be found at OpenNTF. It works, but it isn't Java of course...

Comment: I forgot to say that the JSON is first read from a messaging system and in Java there are great libraries to connect to those services, despite LotusScript... I am using for now the IBM Commons library which does not give me complications with permissions on the Domino server for now it seems although I do not have a direct mapping between the JSON and Java objects but that I can program.

Answer (score 1):

I have just used a Java agent for parsing JSON with GSON . Got the same error, created java.pol file with same full permission and it worked. Remember to set security to allow restricted operations on agent

Comment: may I ask how your java policy file looks like? I am running with allowed restricted operations on the server (with full administrator rights)

Comment: the java.pol has the same content as yours. I should mention that I was manually running the agent in the Notes client, not scheduled on the Domino server.

Comment: I am running the agent manually myself during development. and its not working :-(

Comment: I added my code. do you have a clue why this goes wrong?